# How to get threads to add to only one arrayList of integers with synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, thread-safety, synchronized

I have been trying to do something as simple as get two threads to add to one arraylist, but for whatever reason I cannot get it to work. I have synchronized methods and use Collections.synchronized list but it still shows that it is printing out two separate arrays. I wrote what should have been a short and simple program to get a better understanding of running two threads to access one arrayList. If anyone can shed light and what error I am making it would be deeply appreciated!

Here is the main class

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class RunThreads {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        int[] numbers1 = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};
        int[] numbers2 = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
        executor.execute(new ThreadToRun(numbers1));
        executor.execute(new ThreadToRun(numbers2));
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Here is the TheadToRun class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ThreadToRun implements Runnable {
    List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    private int[] array;

    public ThreadToRun(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public void run() {
        list = adder(array);
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(list.get(i)+"("+i+")"); //print out the element at i and the index 
        }                                            //to see if there are two arrays with the same index
    }

    public  List<Integer> adder(int [] a){
        List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        for (int array : a) {
            synchronized(list){
                list.add(array);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are creating two instances of 'TheadToRun' and each instance instantiates a new instance of list (mentioned below)

```
List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

Also in your adder method you are doing the following:

```
List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

This will create a new list again and overwrite the existing list in the instance.

Possible Solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ThreadToRun implements Runnable {
    List<Integer> list;
    private int[] array;

    public ThreadToRun(int[] array, List<Integer> list) {
        this.array = array;
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int array : a) {
            list.add(array);
        }
    }
}


import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class RunThreads {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        int[] numbers1 = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};
        int[] numbers2 = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};

        List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());

        ThreadToRun t1 = new ThreadToRun(numbers1, list);
        ThreadToRun t2 = new ThreadToRun(numbers1, list);

        executor.execute(t1);
        executor.execute(t2);
        executor.shutdown();

        // print the list out
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(list.get(i) + " found at location ("+i+")");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you two things:

1. The more important point. You are calling the method like `list = adder(array);`. So it will always replace the contents of your ArrayList. Whatever earlier data will be in the list will be *replaced* by the new list returned by the method.

Instead this, you can try it the following way,

`list.add(adder(array));`

2. The other way to create the list will be to declare your list to be `static`. This way it will be common for both your threads and they will enter to the same list.

Answer (score 0):

You create two instances of the syncronized collection (in line 6 of your `ThreadToRun`) - one for each instance of `ThreadToRun`. You have to share the same instance between all threads. There are several ways to do this. E.g. this can be either done by making the list static (which I would not prefer) or by passing an instance to the class via the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are making new arraylists for each instance of 'ThreadToRun'. So they are not the same lists.

You need to share a list between the runnables.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ThreadToRun implements Runnable {
    List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

`list` is an instance member of `ThreadToRun`.  Each time a `ThreadToRun` is created, it sets its `list` to a new `ArrayList`.  That means each thread has its own list.  The two threads are not sharing a list.

There are a number of ways to get it to share a list, but some of them are not recommended (singleton pattern) and some are downright obnoxious (`static` class member).  The cleanest way, probably, is to have the list be a parameter to the constructor.  Then `RunThreads` will create the list and pass it to the constructor of both threads:

```
    List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    executor.execute(new ThreadToRun(numbers1, list));
    executor.execute(new ThreadToRun(numbers2, list));
```

and in `ThreadToRun`:

```
List<Integer> list;
private int[] array;

public ThreadToRun(int[] array, List<Integer> list) {
    this.array = array;
    this.list = list;
}
```

Now your threads will be working with the same list.

There's another problem that I missed at first, because you're using a local variable `list` in your `adder` and it got me confused.  It looks like `adder` creates a second list, which you also call `list`, which I think will be added to the first list.  But since this is a local variable, it will not be shared between threads; therefore `synchronized` is in the wrong place.  I'm not sure what your intent is.  If you want `adder` to actually add to the main `list`, then you can't have a local variable named `list` because that will hide the list.  But if you want `adder` just to create a new list, and have `run` add that new list to the main list, the `synchronized` has to be in `run`, around the code that adds to the main list.  Unfortunately, I can't quite be sure what you're trying to do.